# Regex - searching for a certain number of digits in each line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a table in notepad++ which I try to format and get rid of some digits and points. The table looks something like this:

```
line_a . . 47 34 54 33 44

line_b . . . 43 76 23 44

line_c . . . 32 56 12 34

line_d . 33 87 65 12 23 21

line_e 44 32 76 . . . .
```

What I want to do is to look for the first three entires in each line (no matter if it is a - or a digit) and remove them so that in the end I get this table:

```
line_a 34 54 33 44

line_b 43 76 23 44

line_c 32 56 12 34

line_d 65 12 23 21

line_e . . . .
```

And second I want to look for a line with no digits at all (the last one in this example) and remove it complety.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Search for `^([^ ]+)( [^ ]+){3}` and replace it with `$1`.
This will find the first four strings without a space on each line and replace them with the first of those four strings.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `^(\s*[^ ]+){3}(.*)$` and replace with `\2`

`^` -> beginning of line

`(\s*[^ ]+){3}` -> 3 groups of strings that may (or not) include space/tabs in front of them.

`(.*)$` -> group the rest of the line in group number 2 that we use to replace (`$` denotes the end of line)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Search > Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   ^(?:[.\d]+\s){3}(?:[ .]+$)?(.*)
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   $1
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press `Replace All`

This will *remove the first 3 columns and at the same time will remove completely the points-only lines*. You can test it, have it explained and see the results for your specific example at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/zK6oB0).

[image]

Comment: Hey. In theory this seems to be right, but in notepad++ it doesn't give me any results (the app just says it cannot find this whole string and it seems to match this as a whole and doesn't look for seperate digits and .)?

Comment: Phillip, it's not in theory, I've tested it and you can test too online [here](http://regex101.com/r/xT4hM1)! Can you please tell me your Notepad++ version? If it's lower than 6.0, this is your problem, update it and check again.

Comment: I don't understand it either cause I agree it works here online. Notepad++ is V 6.5 - I even re-downloaded it.

Comment: I am trying to go through the code part by part. The only part that works is: (?:[.\d]+\s){3} - it gives me three chunks of digits, but not if for instance a digit is followed by a . and followed by a digit again and the ^ for the start of a line doesn't work either.

Comment: You are right, due to the "Replace all" nature of N++ the regex wasn't working the same in N++ and in regex101.com. So I changed it a little bit, and I've added a screenshot of the Replace dialog just to be sure that you have set up everything alright. Let me know if it is working now.